# Facebook graph api to get status details not working

Tags: html, facebook-graph-api

I am able to post a message successfully on a USER wall :) , from the code I am trying to  get the status detail which posted thru my application .

Here is the Id for the status message I post on user wall : 557671002_10150464779501003.
When I try get the details about the status message by accessing : https://graph.facebook.com/557671002_10150464779501003 , I get a result as false.
How to get details of status.

Comment: hmm , got it :) I do not have read_stream permission . thanks Lix !

Comment: No problem friend! Please mark this question as answered.

Comment: in your question it says "...unable to post..." - although you are talking about extracting the info of the post you have made from your application.

Answer (score 1):

You have to request the `read_stream` [permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) in order to extract information from a post on a users feed.

Answer (score 0):

Try grabbing it using the access token:

`https://graph.facebook.com/557671002_10150464779501003?access_token={a valid access token}`